# How to parse XML and avoid parsing errors of namespace by setting a default one?

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, xmlpullparser

### Background

I'm trying to parse some manifest XML files of Android APK files

### The problem

I've noticed that in some cases, the XML files aren't valid, meaning that many times there is no namespace being defined, or that for some XML attributes, the namespace isn't used at all.

For example, this is a tiny part of Chrome APK manifest file (it's much longer):

```
<manifest
    versionCode="495157437">

    <uses-sdk
        minSdkVersion="29"/>
    
</manifest>
```

You can see that there is no namespace being defined here, and the attributes don't use one either. In fact, this is what the IDE also generates out of the APK file, so I've reported this [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785585).

In some cases, the XML-attribute would use a namespace that isn't defined

I want to be able to parse such APK, assuming that there is a default namespace (of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` ) and there should be a default usage of it, too as the prefix of each attribute (meaning `android:`).

So, for the above example, it would be as if it's as such:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="495157437">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="29"/>
    
</manifest>
```

In some other weird cases, I saw something like this for an XML attribue:

```
<manifest http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:versionCode="495157437" >
```

### What I've tried

Originally I tried to generate the namespaces on my own so that the input of the parsing would be correct from the beginning, but this became quite complex, so I'm hoping to find a solution that is flexible with the input, so that I would tell it which is the default namespace to use, and it will be as such for all attributes that don't use a namespace.

The code I use to parse the XML from a given string is:

```
fun getXmlFromString(input: String): XmlTag? {
    val factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
    factory.isNamespaceAware = true
    val xpp = factory.newPullParser()
    xpp.setInput(StringReader(input))
    ...
```

Sadly, sooner or later, the XmlPullParser would have an exception about such weird cases.

I still wish to know about other weird issues if they exist, so I let `isNamespaceAware` to stay true.

### The questions

1. Is such a thing possible for XmlPullParser ? I want to capture all these cases, and then treat them using a default namespace in case no valid namespace is found.
2. Alternatively, or even better: Is there some way to fix the XML before parsing it, so that I will tell it what to do with invalid/missing namespaces declaration/usages ?

Note that while this is related to Android, this question could benefit all that use Java/Kotlin.

Comment: I assume that you are unpacking the XML from the APK and then using XmlPullParser to parse it. What are you using to unpack the XML from the APK? Not all attributes have a prefix (see "package" in the manifest documentation), but you have identified some questionable manifests. Why can you use [getAttributePrefix()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser#getAttributePrefix(int)) and [getAttributeNamespace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser#getAttributeNamespace(int)) making assumptions if they return null or an empty string?

Comment: I've created this forked library : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/apk-parser . I don't understand the other questions. I thought that such XML should be valid. It's not some random HTML file over the Internet that some web browser needs to deal with...

Comment: The Chrome manifest from API 28 on a Nexus 6 emulator has no defined name spaces but shows as valid at _www.xmlvalidation.com_. There are other examples within Android of attributes without a name space prefix: `style` and `class` in layout files are two examples. I can't say why that is, but it is acceptable to Android and the validator I mention above.

Comment: From [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces): _It follows that in a namespace-well-formed document: All element and attribute names contain either zero or one colon;_ This implies that attributes do not need a name space prefix to be well-formed.

Comment: I looked at your bug report and validated your uploaded manifest files (android and chrome) on the validation site you mentioned. Both scanned as valid. I may be missing what the true issue is.

Comment: @Cheticamp Odd. It showed that it's invalid when I tested it. Now it shows fine. Should I assume the namespace is "android", then?

Comment: No name space means that the element/attribute has no name space unless it's an element and a default name space is defined. (I think that is true.) I don't know why you want to assign a name space but, if it works for you, I would assume an "android" name space defined the usual way. btw, for Chrome's manifest, ApkTool generates a name space called "n1" defined like the "android" name space and tacks it onto all attributes. It takes care not to attach it to "compileSdkVersion", "package", "platformBuildVersionCode" and "platformBuildVersionName".

Comment: @Cheticamp That's even weirder. Why set new namespaces that don't mean anything anymore?

Comment: Android seems to just seems to just be very forgiving of APKs that are malformed in the strictest sense.

Comment: @Cheticamp OK I see.